# Binary to Decimal - java

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I want to write a program which receive a string value and print the decimal number.

In addition, if the string value is not 1 or 0, I need to print a message.

I wrote this code but it is always getting inside the if command.

I Would appreciate your support!

Thank you

```
import java.util.Random; 
public class Decimal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = (args[0]);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); i++) {
            if (!(input.charAt(i) == '0') || (input.charAt(i) == '1')) {
                System.out.println("wrong string");
                break;
            }
            char a = input.charAt(i);
            if (a == '1') {
                sum |= 0x01;
            }
            sum <<= 1;
            sum >>= 1;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change `!(input.charAt(i) == '0') || (input.charAt(i) == '1')` to `!(input.charAt(i) == '0') && (input.charAt(i) == '1')`

Comment: And that would still be wrong with the parens placed like that.

Comment: Rather sth like (!(input.charAt(i) == '0' || input.charAt(i) == '1'))

Comment: JackWilliams, I've changed it.

Comment: SBI - so what do you recommend please?

Comment: @Dana Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to address a comment to a previous commenter, like you just did, you need to add the `@` sign, so the person is notified, like I just did for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` (not) operator of the `if` statement only applies to the first part:

```
if ( ! (input.charAt(i) == '0')
     ||
     (input.charAt(i) == '1')
   ) {
```

So that is the same as:

```
if ((input.charAt(i) != '0') || (input.charAt(i) == '1')) {
```

When you actually meant to do:

```
if (input.charAt(i) != '0' && input.charAt(i) != '1') {
```

It's a good thing though, because once that works, you're going to get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i == input.length()`. Change the loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
```

And for performance, move variable `a` up and use it in that first `if` statement. Rename to `c` or `ch` is more descriptive/common.

Doing both `sum <<= 1` and `sum >>= 1` leaves you where you started. Is that what you wanted? You should also do the left-shift *before* setting the right-most bit.

Applying all that, I believe you meant to do this:

```
String input = args[0];
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    if (c != '0' && c != '1') {
        System.out.println("wrong string");
        break;
    }
    sum <<= 1;
    if (c == '1')
        sum |= 1;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```